# Compiling certain component file gives Error: The Angular Webpack loader requires the AngularWebpackPlugin

Tags: angular, webpack, compiler-errors

In my angular application I have a `base-page.component` which is inherited by other components. However, when change the `base-page.component` (for example add a space) and recompile, I get the following error:

```
./src/app/shared/components/wizard/page-base/page-base.component.ts?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: The Angular Webpack loader requires the AngularWebpackPlugin.


× Failed to compile.
```

When I change another file and recompile, this error disappears.

I am using the following packages:

```json
    "@angular/core": "14.1.0",

    "@angular/cli": "14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.1.0",

    "webpack": "5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.9.2"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: same error, seems completely random when it happens to me, i can recompile 10 times, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't... wtf

Comment: @Patric In my case, the problem was caused because I used the page-base.component's scss in a file but referenced it wrong. I used `src/... / page-base/page-base.component` instead of `src/... / page-base/page-base.component.scss`